# Python 3 multiple lines loop in shape of a square/rectangle

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I am very new to programming and earlier got some help solving this in Python 3:

"What I am trying to do is a loop with the numbers 0-99. I want the numbers to be in 10*10 rows so it would appear as they form a box, with 0 in the top left corner, and 99 in the bottom right corner. Starting with the first row being 0-9, the second row 10-19, and so on..."

I'm using this code:

```
for row in range(0, 10, 1):
    line = ''
    for col in range(0, 10, 1):
        line = line + str(row*10+col) + " "
    print(line)
```

What I want to do know is make the box perfectly sharp around the edges like a rectangle, but the singulars on the first row makes the row shorter. How would I make the first row be longer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to *left-align* `.ljust(2, ' ')` if the numbers are `0` through `4`, and *right-align* `.rjust(2, ' ')` for all numbers 5 and up.

Example:

```
for row in range(0, 10, 1):
    line = ''
    for col in range(0, 10, 1):
        n = row * 10 + col
        n = str(n).ljust(2, ' ') if n < 5 else str(n).rjust(2, ' ')
        line += n + ' '
    print(line)
```

This will output:

```
0  1  2  3  4   5  6  7  8  9 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 
60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 
70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```